# How to find an embedded submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ which pass through some given points in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and has the lowest dimension?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, low-dimensional-topology

How to find an embedded submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ which pass through some given points in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and has the lowest dimension?

I have no idea with this question. I know, at least, the manifold like this must exist because $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ itself is an embedded manifold which pass through these points, there  is a manifold that has the lowest dimension and pass through these points.

Comment: For a *finite* number of points is simply a curve. For a dense subset the whole space...

Answer (score 0):

If is a finite number of points you can construct a curve simply by interpolation.

Comment: You can just take those finitely many point and forms the zero dimensional submanifold.